# Speed of light is not fixed?

Tags: special-relativity, optics, speed-of-light, spacetime, refraction

In my research, I found that the speed of light is not fixed. IS it true?

Namely, We know that light refracts when the medium it travels through changes. Actually, light travels in the same medium without refraction . This is a relative motion in two dimension.

However, in the medium light up to ‘’(△v)t ’’  is behind of observer. The wavelength of the light entering the medium, shortened according to the wavelength  in  vacuum ( such as a compressed spring). Observed by the observer's motion a relative movement. According to       v > v2.    (v2 =c ). In water  do not refracted light only according to the observer, up to (△v)t  been remains behind in time. So, speed of the observer  is greater than  speed of light in the medium. Electromagnetic waves loses speed while passing inside medium.

I tested it several times, it is possible to explain with equations of relative motion in two dimension.

This mean is that; speed of our universe is ''c'' and same direction spherical wave and this speed creates time. ( All masses are moving in the same direction with speed of ''c'',  this way we can not observe this speed)

I also observed this; the light coming from upright  to x and y coordinates ( Normal)  do not refract, but shorter (We observe an object  a higher position than initial position in water) . Is this right?

We can explain this with the equations of relative motion in two dimention. How can we, assuming the Fermat and snell says true? How can I explain it with the equations of relative motion in two dimensions? If I am wrong, could you please explain me why.

Comment: The speed of light is only fixed in a vacuum. Going faster than light in a medium leads to [Cherenkov radiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cherenkov_radiation). I'm sorry, but it's really hard to tell what you're saying here. Also, see the [faq#questions], especially the "Pitches for your own personal theories or work" section.

Answer (score 2):

Speed of light in vacuum is constant and maximum. First physicist to point this out was Albert Einstein. This statement is not that trivial as it may appear. Even for the "great" minds it took some time to understand what this may mean. However, in a medium speed of light could be less than its maximum value. For more information you can look at [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_of_light) on wikipedia. For technical information about it you can look at Griffiths book on electrodynamics. One other book that is quite well written, nontechnical, and could be very useful to read in this context is Feynman's *QED, the strange theory of light and matter*.

Edit : Answers to following questions on this site could also be of relevance to you :

1.) [how-is-the-speed-of-light-calculated](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/5194/how-is-the-speed-of-light-calculated)

2.) [the-origin-of-the-value-of-speed-of-light](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/3644/the-origin-of-the-value-of-speed-of-light)